# Using grep to finding long digit series and inserting thin spaces into them

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, grep

On my page i have a table with over 500 rows, in it one column where all cells contain a different numbers, such as 55123, 666000, 3000 and 1459000 (figures for sums of money). I would need to insert thin spaces in the numbers for them to be easier to read, according to the following scheme:

Seven digits in a row is changed to:
d ddd ddd (eg 1 459 000, d=digit)

six to:
  ddd ddd (eg. 666 000)

five to:
   dd ddd (eg. 55 123)

Four to:
    d ddd (eg. 3000)

using find/change I am able to find all instances of for example 7 digits in a row with the grep line \d{7} but i am lost at having a command for how to "change" using the found numbers and adding a thin space at the right positions.

Is there a way of writing a script or a find/change query for this operation for doing this anywhere in the text (or just the table)? Any tips on this are much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Julius, welcome to GD.SE! If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the matching engine (at least in my indesign) we will fix this first.

- Find:

  `(.)\Z`
- Replace

  `$1:`
- Replace All

Ok now we have a anchor at the end of story. Now for the magic:

- Find:

  `(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(:|\s))`

  Explanation match any digit followed by any number triplet of digits and : or any whitespace
- Replace

  `$1~<`

  Number and thin space
- Replace All

And now let us fix end marker back:

- Find:

  `:\d`
- Replace

  leave empty
- Replace All

Done.

**PS**: you can try if `(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+\Z)` works, it does not work on my machine.